# Extract Input parameters from "mxnet" model

Tags: deep-learning, mxnet

I have saved the model using

```
mx.model.save(model = fit_dl, prefix = "model", iteration = 10)
```

and loaded later

```
fit <- mx.model.load(prefix = "model", iteration = 10)
```

Now, using object fit, I want to extract the input features (column names of train data). How to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting for sake of all open source community

As per my email exchange with maintner of mxnet packge, Qiang Kou  replies following

From: Qiang Kou 
To: Shiv Onkar Kumar  
Sent: Wednesday, 14 June 2017 10:33 PM
Subject: Re: Extract Input parameters from “mxnet” model

Hi, Shiv,

I don't this is possible since we never store this information in the model.

Best,
Qiang Kou